# Tweet using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to create a client side tweet using javascript, a textbox, and a submit button? The process would be to enter text to tweet into the textbox, press the button then tweet it using an authenticated account all on the client side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Yes".

That said, you need to get an authenticated account on the client side. Twitter does expose mostly RESTful API's for all sorts of things including [submitting tweets](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) which you would be able to access via AJAX, however the act of logging in may be difficult due to Twitters reliance on [OAuth as a login mechanism](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#intro). I'm not sure how you could get around that in a totally client-side manner.

Comment: How could I go about authenticating them with javascript? Does OAuth support authentication using JS?

Comment: @cfarm54 part of the OAuth 'dance' is redirecting your user to the Twitter website, which redirects them back to your website, and Twitter needs a publicly accessible HTTP server to send stuff to behind the scenes from the client. In short, not really. You can read the link in my answer for all the gritty details if you want.

Comment: This is helpful additional information, for the single-user use-case: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking for, but you can also have users post to Twitter like this:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Custom%20status%20here" target="_blank">Post to Twitter!</a>`

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution for me was to reference http://twitter.com/share on a client side button or anchor tag and use twitter to log-in log-out. Granted the downside is I don't get to customize my look and feel of the input (except for the words that I can default set), but it's the only way I could find the client side to work without OAuth.

`<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=&" target="_blank">Create a Tweet</a>`

Any other ways where I can enable more flexibility in my design are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter's @anywhere using something like this:

```
        twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
            T.Status.update("Hello World");
        });
```

More info here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome

Comment: Alas Twitter has retired @Anywhere, only valid till Dec 06 2012